# parseerror invalid XML: 601

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
    var ajaxLoader = $('.ajaxLoader', lpWindow);
$.ajaxSetup({
    url: 'http://www.server.foo/setMessage.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        text: message,
        username: username
    },

    beforeSend: function(){
        ajaxLoader.fadeIn( 'fast' );
    },
    complete: function(){
        ajaxLoader.fadeOut( 'fast' );
    },
    success: function(){
        ajaxLoader.fadeOut( 'fast' );
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        $('.content', lpWindow).empty().append('Something went wrong...');
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(thrownError);

    }
});

$.ajax({
    success: function(){
        getMessages(lpWindow)
    }
});
```

It works perfect in Google Chrome but it fail in firefox. i get this error messages in firebug.

200
parsererror
Invalid XML: 601

What's wrong and how can i solve it?

Comment: Can you post a sample response as well?

Comment: What type of content is in setMessage.php? Have you tried setting content-type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the request succeeds but your XML in the response is invalid. Ensure you're sending back valid XML.

**EDIT**

If you're not actually sending back XML, make sure to set at least one of the following with right data type (the examples below are for JSON):

- The `Content-Type` header on the server (`header('Content-type: application/json');` for PHP)
- The `dataType` parameter for the Ajax request (`dataType:'json'`)

Comment: I'm not allowed to edit the .php file. so i can't change anything in the .php.

Comment: @Tord Fair enough. But you haven't answered the basic question - what is the data that the PHP returns? Is it XML? Can you post a sample response to help debug?

Comment: I do not have permission to change the php file. I tried putting dataType: 'xml', in the ajax request, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Tord Ok, can you post a sample? And can you check that your XML is valid? Run it through an XML validator and see if it passes.

Comment: http://j7.se/9cqwp - click on the green icon chat icon. i checked the manual for setMessage.php and it says: Address: http://adress.com/setMessage.php
Method:
POST
Parameters:
Text: Using this parameter is sent in the message text. username: Via this parameter is passed in the username.
Return:
If the message is stored properly, it will contain the response a unique ID for the message.

Comment: I took a look at the response - the content type being set by the server is `text/html` and not XML (although the text itself is well-formed XML); that's probably the root of your problem. But if using `dataType:'text'` works for you then great!