# jQuery ajax() function is ignoring dataType parameter in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, firefox

I'm trying to use jQuery.ajax() to fetch some html, but Firefox is giving me a "junk after document element" error message. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441020/jquery-ajax-exception-only-in-firefox-node-cannot-be-inserted-at-the-specified) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354210/jquery-ajax-problem-in-firefox) the problem seems to be that Firefox is expecting XML from the server, and when it doesn't parse correctly it throws the error. Here's my ajax code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: name,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

The server returns the html with these response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Length  2957
Last-Modified   Tue, 02 Jul 2013 16:16:59 GMT
```

Note that there's no content-type header. I'm sure that adding one would solve the problem, but that's not an option.

The real problem is that Firefox appears to be ignoring the dataType: parameter in the ajax call. I've also tried adding contentType: and accepts: parameters, but it doesn't help.

What am I missing here? How do I force Firefox to process the response as plain text?

Comment: RoR ... FireFox ... bleh, sounds like you're fighting the new IE in browsers and the ... well, never anything nice to say about RoR. I still don't see a use in it. Much as I hate to say it, this is either an issue with `Content-type` header or you need to double check, maybe var_dump in another browser, or write it to file, but double check you XML is in it's proper schema

Comment: Thanks, but it's not XML. It's HTML.

Comment: Ah, I misread. hmm .... have you tried a plain and simple `echo` of the HTML as string? Of course, I'd recommend you console the result as `console.log($('<div />').html(result))`. That way you see it as a jQuery object instead of a giant string in your console. That also gives you the ability to parse through the HTML using `.find`

Comment: @ccleve try setting `dataType : 'text'` for plaintext. Failing that, try `dataType : 'xml text'`, which tells jQuery to convert all XML to plaintext (worth a shot). What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I just tried it. 'text' gives the same error. 'xml text' gives the same error twice, which is odd. I was using jQuery 1.9.1, but I just upgraded to 2.0.2 and it yields the same error.

Comment: One other thought, I know you're in RoR, but you still have `json_encode`?  Try `echo(json_encode($html));` and set your `dataType` to either `text` or `json`. Just try it. Been a long while since i've RoRd, so I'm grasping at old skool PhP straws here, but something to try. See the result.

Comment: I'm not in RoR. As I mention in the post, setting the content-type on the server side solves the problem, but it's not an option here.

Comment: @ccleve I would try playing around with the `converters` option. Try `converters : {"text xml" : true}`, failing that try: `converters : {"text xml" : function(value){ return value; }}`. The converters lets you override jQuery's default converter, so maybe you can override the XML converter to return the plain text instead of the default of using `$.parseXML()`.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue 6 year later...

Answer (score 1):

The above code is working fine.

you can use the below code. As I noticed your file should be saved in .txt format.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test.txt",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const res = parser.parseFromString(result, 'text/html');
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I have tested this code in Firefox and it's working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How does the HTML response look? If it doesn't already, I would try and make sure that the response starts with a doctype declaration on the first line, as in `<!doctype html>`.

With a bit of luck, this could bring Firefox' content type detection onto the right track.

Answer (score -3):

Alright, so you can try `"HTML"` instead of `"html"`.

Comment: Are you sure? Are you absolutely sure?